Delete background from Button (React, JS, SCSS)
somehow I cant delete the backgroundcolor of my Button
Left is withbackground, and right is a Link without, but its almost the same CSS design.
enter image description here
button.navButton {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  Border: 0;
}

Also i have this hover and this works.
button.navButton:hover {
  background-color: $background-color-hover;
}

ChatGPT cant help xD

Have you tried declaring background value for  button.navButton
button.navButton {
 ...
  background-color: none;
}


thanks, but it didnt work.
Now I found a solution:
background-color: transparent;
(SCSS)
